# Dead link in the 'create chat room' page

Tags: bug, chat, broken-link

The 'create a new chat room' page has a dead link. There is a link to 'the help center', trying to go to https://stackexchange.com/help/licensing, but that link doesn't go anywhere anymore.

I was trying to use this page to find out what the licensing is for images posted into the chat, and I was unable to find out this way.

Comment: Worth mentioning this is only broken on [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new). The MSE and SO chat servers are unaffected as the link there works due to how their domain names match an existing help center